# Using session to store cookies and check login

Tags: php

I am using `$_SESSION` to store cookies as I need certain variables to be set upon `login.php` to be used on other place.

On my login.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
} 
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = 1;
$_SESSION['loggedInID'] = $id;
$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $isAdmin; // 1 for admin, else 0
```

On my `admin.html` page which will call `admin.js` that would do ajax call to `admin.php` upon load. I need to check whether is the user logged in is an admin.

I did this on my admin.php.

```
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['isAdmin']) && $_SESSION['isAdmin'] != 1)) {
    echo 'Not logged in as admin';
}
```

But now on my admin page, admin.php keeps echo "Not logged in as admin";

Why is that so?

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` at the top of your admin page? You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I did. They are at the top of the page.

Comment: Try `$_SESSION['isAdmin'] != '1'` ?

Comment: Your if statement is at odds with itself. if it is not set and not equal to one you will get the result. You likely want to see if it is set and not equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need OR instead of AND:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['isAdmin']) || $_SESSION['isAdmin'] != 1) {
```

Now, if the variable is set, the first condition is false so the second one will be checked. Only if the second condition is met (not logged in as admin), you will see the warning.

Comment: Yea. Most answer works find but I would pick yours. Anyway why do we need to check whether is it set first by invoking `isset` method. Why can't we just go straight into checking for the variable value itself?

Comment: @MaTaKazer That would lead to an "undefined index" warning in php. Normally warnings are not displayed, but they should be during development so that you catch things like accidentally working with undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets say `isset($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == true` and lets say `$_SESSION['isAdmin'] == 1`. So currently your if looks like this:

```
if(!(true && 1!=1)) {
 ...
}
```

so you then get

```
if(!(true && false)) {
     ...
    }
```

furthermore, you get

```
if(!(false)) {
     ...
    }
```

which really means true. Try something like this instead:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['isAdmin']) || $_SESSION['isAdmin'] != 1) {
    echo 'Not logged in as admin';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incase of *$isAdmin = 1* in the example you give renders to:

```
if (!(true && false)) {
    echo 'Not logged in as admin';
}
```

this is why you will get the echo result *Not logged in as admin*

Answer (score -1):

Check if the variable is defined before see it's value

```
 session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['isAdmin']) {
        if($_SESSION['isAdmin'] != 1) {
            echo 'Not logged in as admin';
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why "will this be better"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: No, now the script will not display the message if the variable is not set. Which is wrong as you are not logged in as admin.

Comment: You need to check if variable is defined and AFTER see it value, so use:

Comment: Nesting the conditions is the same as using AND so this does not change anything.